# Angular 6 app in .NET MVC 5, angular routing doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, model-view-controller, routes

I've embedded an Angular 6 app in an existing .NET MVC 5 application.  I added a fallback route pointed to Home/Index in the MVC app (RouteConfig.cs), so "unknown" routes would pass to the Angular app's router module (app.routes.ts).  The Angular app's routes do not appear to be firing, the component associated with the path doesn't load.

The IDE is Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.6.7, the MVC app is standard .NET Web application (not .NET Core), MVC 5.2.3.0; Node.js 8.11.3, npm 6.3.0, Typescript 2.9.2, Angular CLI 6.0.8, Angular 6.0.3; bootstrap 3.3.7, jquery 3.3.1; OS: Win 10 x64.

The MVC app's RouteConfig.cs is below; the catch-all route is at the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Ang2Mvc5_0
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "mvc",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            // This is a catch-all for when no other routes match the request; let the Angular 2 router take care of it...
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // The view that bootstraps Angular 2 app
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I created the Angular app (using CLI), the package.json entry for Typescript defaults to 2.7.2; package.json is below, the ngf-bootstrap entry is specific for a PluralSight tutorial.

Am I missing something?

```
{
    "name": "temp-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "ngf-bootstrap": "0.0.5",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2"
    }
}
```

The app.routes.ts is below; it's really simple, so far, I've not progressed very far into the app development.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { EventsListComponent } from './events/events-list.component'
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './events/event-details/event-details.component'

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsListComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'events/:id',
        component: EventDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/events'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The EventsAppModule is below; note @ line 16, I've imported the AppRoutingModule (app.routes.ts), I can comment this line to disable routing.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { EventsAppComponent } from './events-app.component';
import { EventsListComponent } from './events/events-list.component';
import { EventThumbnailComponent } from './events/event-thumbnail.component';
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './events/event-details/event-details.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav/navbar.component';
import { EventService } from './events/shared/event.service';
import { ToastrService } from './common/toastr.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
        , AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        EventsAppComponent,
        EventsListComponent,
        EventThumbnailComponent,
        EventDetailsComponent,
        NavBarComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        EventService,
        ToastrService
    ],
    bootstrap: [EventsAppComponent]
})

export class EventsAppModule { }
```

As noted, when trying to use routing, with the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in the app's main component/page, the EventsListComponent doesn't load (I get a blank page).  If I comment the AppRoutingModule from the app's module and switch to the `<events-list></events-list>` tag in the app's main component, the EventsListComponent loads fine (it displays a list of events, each encapsulated in an EventThumbnailComponent).

Also, it doesn't load http://localhost:39420/events when I run; it defaults to root, e.g., localhost:39420/ ...if I type '/events' in the url, I don't get an error, just a blank page. If I try to get the EventDetailsComponent, using localhost:39420/events/1 ...again, it just renders a blank page.

Comment: `redirectTo: 'events'` should be         `redirectTo: '/events'`

Comment: Thanks, good point (fixed).  Doesn't address the main issue, though?

Comment: What's the url you're trying to navigate to again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirectTo` expects the exact path to which the router should navigate to. So it expects a `/` before route path that you might have defined.

Replace `redirectTo: 'events'` with `redirectTo: '/events'` in your route config and it should load `EventsListComponent` component properly.

Also add a `pathMatch: 'full'` to this route:

```
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/events',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
```

Here's a [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sample-routing-eg) to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I wish it was that simple.  Unfortunately, after fixing that I'm still experiencing the same behavior.  Also, it doesn't actually load /events, when I run it; it defaults to root, e.g., http://localhost:39420/  ...instead of http://localhost:39420/events  ...if I type that in, I don't get an error, jusat a blank page.  If I try to get the EventDetailsComponent, using http://localhost:39420/events/1 ...again, it just renders a blank page.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz if possible? There could be several issues possible. You might have forgotten to import AppRoutingModule in your AppModule.

Comment: I edited the question, added my AppModule; as noted above (last paragraph), the AppRoutingModule is imported; I've toggled commenting it to determine the routing is what's "breaking" the app.

Comment: Thanks for the StackBlitz, I tried it and everything works as expected.  If I were just doing a standalone Angular app (not embedded in an MVC app), I'd expect the same behavior - I've done exactly that previously, standalone Angular apps work fine in my dev environment.  It's something about adding the Angular app to a .NET MVC app, the MVC app wants to handle routing on each postback. For whatever reason, it seems the catch-all route is not passing the request through to Angular routing; it appears the Angular routing is just not firing.  I'm not even sure how to diagnose it.

Comment: My bad, I missed a piece of your advice: adding the pathMatch: 'full' to the default (empty) route helped a lot.  My routing issues are still not entirely solved, but your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> So this is what you have to catch all when no other routes match the request so that Angular can handle it.

```
// This is a catch-all for when no other routes match the request; let the Angular 2 router take care of it...
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // The view that bootstraps Angular 2 app
            );
```

> You need to remove the defaults so it will look like this. And don't create a Controller/View for angular.

```
// This is a catch-all for when no other routes match the request; let the Angular 2 router take care of it...
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                url: "{*url}",// you don't need a view
            );
```

> After you run the command

**ng build --prod**

> copy the dist files into a directory ex(myangularapp) withing the root
>   directory of you mvc app. you will need to change the base  tag href
>   attribute so run

**ng build --prod --base-href=/myangularapp/**.

> Then you can add a web.config file to the the directory that holds your angular files (myangularapp). Sample below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
        <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```