# How to stop ASP.NET MVC from interfering with Angular routing?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, angular13

I am trying to get Angular to work with ASP.NET MVC by following [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-angular-with-asp-net-mvc-5-on-iis/) tutorial. So far, after a lot of trial & error I was able to get it to work for the most part. However, the ASP.NET MVC routing is still causing me a lot of trouble and I don't know what to do about this. For example, when I navigate to another page in the frontend, it works fine but as soon as I refresh the page I get a 404 error, because the backend does not know what to do with the Angular route.

I also noticed that a few minor things like for example the hamburger menu icon in the Angular application are not displayed properly. Instead of the icon it just displays the text "menu". I assume that this is also related to the routing not working properly.

This is how my `RegisterRoutes` implementation looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Angular", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Angular",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Angular", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

The second route mapping is just an attempt to solve the routing problem which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046412/angular-6-app-in-net-mvc-5-angular-routing-doesnt-work) SO question, but it does not seem to be working in my case.

In my backend, I have the following Index.cshtml to return the Angular page to the web browser:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/angular-css")
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
</body>
</html>
```

To return this as a `View`, I implemented the following controller:

```
public class AngularController : Controller
{
    // GET: Angular
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

How can I configure the routing in ASP.NET MVC so it does not interfere with the Angular routing?

Comment: Post your Angular code. MVC doesn't interfere because it runs on the *server*. For some reason the Angular code fails to catch the route and sends the request to the server instead. If the Angular code worked, the request would never reach the server

Comment: Besides, Visual Studio already has an SPA project that uses Angular or React. And ASP.NET Core 5 reaches End Of Life along with .NET 5 on May 2022. The long-term-support versions are 3.1 and 6.0. 5.0 was only supported for a year. This is nothing new, the support lifecycle was announces back when 3.0 was released

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am talking about the situation when the user initially navigates to the specific route. In that situation, The server first has to handle the request because the Angular app is not yet loaded on the client side. If I initially navigate to the root route and then navigate inside the Angular app itself, it works just fine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is impossible for me to use a newer framework version because in this project I have to use multiple 3rd party libraries which only exist for .NET Framework and also do not have a .NET Core X.X or .NET 6 version announced so far. The SPA project you mentioned is (to my knowledge) not available for ASP.NET MVC (not Core).

Comment: So you mean the *other* 5. Even then, there's actual, official documentation for this. Check [this hands-on lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) for example. Since you're building an SPA you don't need MVC, only Web API. On the other hand, these are legacy technologies. Angular in particular changes much faster than ASP.NET (Core). What do those third-party libraries do? Are there no new versions?

Comment: Perhaps you should split the web app project from the code that uses those old libraries, create a separate ASP.NET Framework Web API project just for those libraries, and call it from your web app. It's not just that ASP.NET is legacy, the entire Angular toolchain has changed a lot. If you don't know how to deal with all the tools already, you may end up debugging obsolete versions (webpack for example) and having to handle bugs that were resolved years ago. You may have to manually upgrade the individual tools *and* make them work with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Another option would be to build the Angular and Web API projects completely separately, and have the Angular project call the Web API project.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, there are no new versions and there is also an official statement from the developers that they currently do not persue .NET Core support in favor of other work. Anyway, I actually started this project by using Web API instead of MVC but that way I was not able to figure out a way to deploy this application easily. The only option I found would have been to deploy the frontend and backend seperately which would then require me to deal with CORS and all sorts of other things I don't know anything about and therefore want to avoid.

Comment: If you can't get this to work with Web API, going back to an even older technology like MVC will make things a lot harder, not easier. Did you actually try the hands-on lab at learn.microsoft.com? `I don't know anything about and therefore want to avoid.` you're there already. You're trying to use things that weren't built to work together from the start. As for CORS, you can't even think about SPAs without understanding CORS. `I was not able to figure out a way to deploy this application easily` that was solved in the ASP.NET Core templates

Comment: Instead of trying to solve the entire problem at once, with obsolete technologies. split it apart. Create an ASP.NET Core Angular SPA and get it to work. Then create a separate ASP.NET Web API and get *that* to work. Then, have the ASP.NET Core controllers call the Web API with plain HttpClient calls. There are a *lot* of tutorials and courses on using ASP.NET Core with Angular. By the time you create the SPA web app you'll probably know how to handle CORS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The thing is, it might sound easy from your perspective to just ditch the MVC project and solve the problem by using an ASP.NET Core Angular SPA. The reality is that I have not even made the final decision to use MVC because I am not the project manager. I am just the guy implementing what has already been discussed and planned. As much as I'd prefer to implement this based on .NET 6, I can't just throw this project away and do something else.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If there is a technical limitation which makes this impossible to implement with MVC, I can start a discussion on this and maybe cause a change which would allow me to use .NET Core or 6. As long as there are just arguments regarding the support lifecycle or other annoyances and risks, argumenting about this and justifying the efforts for implementing those changes will be very tedious, especially since I do not yet have that much experience in web development.

Comment: EOL isn't annoyance. It's a "you're on your own for everything now". Besides, the problem now is that you're unfamiliar with Angular and SPA concepts like CORS. You can try to tackle each problem alone to understand how they work, or you can try do do everything at once *and* backport the unfamiliar Angular toolchain to ASP.NET MVC. Something that didn't work when you tried Web API, which at least was built for that purpose. MVC is older and doesn't even have good JSON support.

Comment: At the very least try the *Microsoft* tutorials like [Hands On Lab: Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs). If something doesn't work, don't assume Web API is broken.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The thing with EOL is, this project will replace a legacy application which is built on 20+ years old technology. This application is going to be used for decades and anything I could implement today will be used longer than even the longest possible support lifespan. Therefore, nobody who can make decisions in this project really cares about the support lifespan of the used technologies, as long as they are still somewhat up-to-date. There are so many old technologies involved already that it is impossible to implement this without technologies that already reached EOL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Anyway, you convinced me that I should talk about this and see if I can get it implemented based on .NET 6. I agree that it makes much more sense than using technologies that were not made to be used together to begin with.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Success! I am allowed to replace the MVC app with an ASP.NET Core Angular SPA. Thanks a lot for the heads-up.